# PHP: write hash to url with php?

Tags: php, html, hash

i know it's not possible to get the hashvalue of an url with php, cause it's already executed on the server, but is it possible to write a hashvalue to a url with php like you can do with javascript?

regards matt

Comment: hashvalue of a url? what does that mean? hashes of anything can be calculated.  Your question is very vague, provide an example of what you thinks is possible in javascript.

Comment: oh, sorry i mean #hashtag like in twitter! someurl.com#whatever
in js you top.location.hash = whatever

Comment: #hashtags are mainly based for anchors within the HTML page, what you are looking for is PHP isset with the GET value, but no you can't do that with a Hash.

Answer (score 0):

Like this...?

```
<a href="http://example.com/foo<?php echo '#bar'; ?>">My Link</a>
```

Of course you won't be able to do it "like Javascript", since PHP does not work on the client side like Javascript. You can *make* links with an anchor part though, it's just strings.

Answer (score 0):

> hey, i know it's not possible to get
>   the hashvalue of an url with php,
>   cause it's already executed on the
>   server

That's right.

> but is it possible to write a
>   hashvalue to a url with php like you
>   can do with javascript?

You should be right again :P, you need ***javascript*** for that.